# is.error() can't find funtion what is the Rpackage: R exception handling

Tags: r

How to do exception handling in R inside a loop? Here is what I am trying to do.

```
raiz <- "https://www.dsn.gob.es/es/actualidad/sala-prensa/coronavirus-covid-19-"
raiz2 <- "https://www.dsn.gob.es/es/actualidad/sala-prensa/coronavirus-covid19-"
parrafos <- c()

length(fechas.enlaces) 
for (i in 1:88) {
 if(is.error(pagina.parrafo <- read_html(paste0(raiz,fechas.enlaces[i])))){
   pagina.parrafo <- read_html(paste0(raiz2,fechas.enlaces[i]))
 }else{pagina.parrafo <- read_html(paste0(raiz,fechas.enlaces[i]))} 

   grupo <- html_nodes(pagina.parrafo, xpath = '//div[@class="field-items"]/div/p')
   pos.parrafo <- which(str_detect(grupo, pattern = "casos|asciende|fallecidos|fallecimiento"))
  if (length(pos.parrafo) == 0) {
    parrafo <- NA
  } else {
    parrafo <- html_children(grupo)[pos.parrafo[1]]
    parrafo <- html_text(grupo)[pos.parrafo[1]]
  }
  parrafos <- c(parrafos,parrafo) 

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Explain what you were trying to achieve and how you got to the snippet that you have.

Answer (score 1):

The function `is.error()` is not a part of base R, it's part of an additional package called BBmisc. Before you use it, you need to load that package like this: `library(BBmisc)`. If you have not installed the package yet you need to run `install.packages('BBmisc')` before anything else.